# Angular2 loop through array within object

Tags: object, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I got an object `project` which contains some properties and an array, when I try to loop trough it like this it's not working:

`<img *ngFor="let image of {{project?.acf.images}}" src="{{image.image.url}}">`

When I display it like this: `{{project?.acf.images[0].image.url}}`, it perfectly shows the url. Anything wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interpolation is not needed in `NgFor` directive:

```
<img *ngFor="let image of project?.acf.images" src="{{image.image.url}}">
```

Comment: Ah damm that was stupid haha, thanks mate! (will accept answer in 10 min, not allowed before then).